# Minecraft server manager

Tags: haskell

I wanna write a Haskell script which handles interaction with a minecraft server.

To send commands to the server, I have a file `server.cmd` where in the first line 1 command can be written which should be executed in the server (e.g. `stop`).

So, here is my code:

```
-- servermanager.hs

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-warnings-deprecations #-}

module ServerManager where

import System.Process
import System.Exit
import GHC.IO.Handle
import Control.Monad
import System.Posix.Unistd

managerfile :: FilePath
managerfile = "manager.cmd"

serverfile :: FilePath
serverfile = "server.cmd"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (Just hin, _, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "java" ["-jar", "minecraft_server.1.8.9.jar", "nogui"]) {cwd = Just "/home/tekkkz/Downloads", std_in = CreatePipe, std_out = CreatePipe}
  sleep 20
  servercmd <- readFile serverfile
  case servercmd of
    "stop" -> do
      putStrLn ">> [S] Stop"
      hPutStr hin "stop"
    _ -> return ()
```

When there is "stop" in my server.cmd file, it print's out the string but is not stopping the server ... why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't flush the pipe, due to the lazyness of `IO` actions the program silently terminate before `hPutStr` has a chance to do its job.

Try add this line after `hPutStr hin "stop"`:

```
hFlush hin
```